# how to get all the values whose node names starts with kpk with only one string output

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i get the values whose nodes starts with KPK or PU, as i only know the provinces/state names.
or how can i get only "node names" which starts with KPK.
or is there any structure which i can follow to get cities names starts with KPK/PU.
I just want to save city names and I only know province/state names.I want the  modal class having only one string variable as cities will be added in future.So want to have a generic modal class.

[image: my firebase structure]

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Also: what have you already tried?

Comment: im using firebase in Android,java.

Comment: i have used every single query with every type of tweaking to get the cities of a province kpk or PU.

Comment: The main problem is i didnt know the key or value,but what i can do is i can save all the cities starts with the province/state name to get names easily.

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure you have two options:

1. Read all data under the root of what you've shown and filter client-side.
2. Perform two reads: one for every node that starts with `kpk_` and one for every node that starts with `pu_`. And then merge them on the client.

The first approach is simpler, but reads too much data. The second approach only read the data that is needed, but the code will be more complex.

There actually is a third approach that will work with your current structure, but may stop working of you add more data. You can start **at** `kpk_` and end at `pu_~`. This range includes exactly the nodes you want in the current JSON.

The code will be something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/path/to/data");
ref.orderByKey().startAt("kpk_").endAt("pu_~").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(child.getKey()+": "+child.getValue(String.class));
    }
  }
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException();
  }
});
```

Note that in general it is recommended to keep only data of a single type under a node. If you have a use-case where you need the `pu_*` and `kpk_*`, then consider adding an additional node in your JSON where you keep only those values. While it is more complex to write this additional structure, it will be more efficient and simpler to read.